# Strange AVPlayer behavior with HLS redundant streams and bad network

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I have an app which can play video HLS streams.
HLS master playlist contains redundant steams to provide backup service

Looks like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1500000,RESOLUTION=638x480
https://example.com/playlist.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1564000,RESOLUTION=638x480
https://example.com/playlist.m3u8?redundant=1
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1564000,RESOLUTION=638x480
https://example.com/playlist.m3u8?redundant=2
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1564000,RESOLUTION=638x480
https://example.com/playlist.m3u8?redundant=3

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=400000,RESOLUTION=638x480
https://example.com/playlist_lq.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=400000,RESOLUTION=638x480
https://example.com/playlist_lq.m3u8?redundant=1
....
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=400000,RESOLUTION=638x480
https://example.com/playlist_lq.m3u8?redundant=5
```

So, I decided to test out how this setup will fly in case of a bad network scenario. For this, I used network link conditioner's 3G preset, which provides 750kbs of download bandwidth. Naturally I expected relatively smooth playback of 400kbs video but alas, it took 60 seconds to fully load test clip (800kb total size).

What I noticed is that AVPlayer sends requests for all listed redundant playlist (and I have 5 for each bandwidth). If I remove them and keep only 1 media-playlist per bandwidth - video loads in 10 seconds and plays without hiccups.

It looks like AVPlayer try to process all redundant links in parallel with main video load and chokes hard.

Is there any way to restrict this behavior of AVPlayer and force him to go for redundant streams only in case of actual load error?
Any idea why it tries to load all of them? Maybe some HLS tags can help?

Also it sometimes display errors like this in console:

```
{OptimizedCabacDecoder::UpdateBitStreamPtr} bitstream parsing error!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

And I cant find much info about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in incorrectly set BANDWIDTH value, AVPlayer has some obscure logic with switching redundant streams if property current one doesn't match m3u8 values